# Jquery Date Picker Date format to MM - DD- CCYY.

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to get the date format of jquery date picker to the US format MM - DD- CCYY. Kindly help to get this one.

```
$(function() {
   $("#lstsdate").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "mm-dd-ccyy");
})
```

`mm/dd/yyyy returns 05/14/2014`.
`mm-dd-ccyy returns 05/14/2114`
where cc is century..

Comment: Why do you want to use such obscure format "ccyy"?

Comment: Thats the requirement given to me.